# Can I program a Breadboard with a laptop?

Tags: power-supply, breadboard, laptop

I want to be able to program a breadboard with a laptop, male to male usb cord, powersupply circuit board (which has a usb in port) and breadbord. My question is, Will this setup work??

Basically because my Raspberry pi does not work anymore, I am wondering is there another way to comunicate (code) with a curcuit (on a breadboard) using an old laptop (Windows Vista)? I hope this question makes sense.

For example, could I type up a code that makes a led blink every second on the laptop and then be sent down a usb to breadboard with a powersupply piece on it that has a usb in-port?

Comment: *Will this setup work* - work how?  It might as a *presse-papier*.

Comment: No but there is software called, [Virtual Breadboard](http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/) that can simulate a breadboard. As far as trying to get your breadboard to work, you need to know some circuit analysis for that :)

Comment: see my comment below

Comment: I read your comment under Michel's answer. I'm still a confused. I _think_ what you're asking for is a way to code your pins to _do something_ to your circuit. If that is the case, then Michel is correct. You will need some integrated circuits (ICs) to that.

Comment: If you mean *control* a breadboard over USB, look at something like this : https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=351346&country=be&lang=en You can read and set a few logic levels, and read and set two analog signals (voltages) over USB, and connect all those via wires from the screw terminals to your breadboard.

Comment: OP seems to be asking can s/he program a device on a breadboard. This is a very poorly worded question.

Comment: If you mean push Arduino code from PC via USB port which has a boot loader at 9600 Bd.  yes there are utilities to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot program a breadboard. A breadboard is just a bunch of metal strips connected with each other in a structure. If you mean you want to change this structure, than the answer is no. At least not directly.

You can use special ICs (called multiplexers/demultiplexers) to redirect inputs/outputs the way you want. This way you can program (or control) the way the connections (wires) will behave.

To program this however, you need a microcontroller (or any other electrical way), and still cannot be done via USB.

But before detailing out possibilities, maybe it's best to describe the problem you have, instead of your proposed 'possible solution'.

Comment: thanks for the help. when I say program I am talking about the curcuit. Like connecting raspberry pi to a breadboard just on a laptop and a usb instead of using pins on a pi.

Comment: (Claps) Yay! You got 3k rep! :D

Comment: Theorethically you can use the USB signals to 'control' your circuit, but that would be a hell of a job, probably needing to find out exactly  how the USB protocol works, and convert the data sentn over the USB to signals that can be used into your circuit. Using a microprocessor will be much more easier.

Comment: @KingDuken Thanks :-) (and sorry for the late reaction)

Comment: (way to rub it in, now you have over 6.5k rep) lol

Comment: @KingDuken Not my intention; actually looking at your profile I am sure you have much more electronical knowledge than I do (but I try to help people too, since I get a lot of help from people here).